# Listen to all form submit events and perform a function before any other attached event handlers

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, csrf

I'm trying to prevent [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks in a an existing large web app. I've opted for a token that is injected using JS into any form and a Java Servlet filter that will check for its presence before allowing the request to continue. Firstly we are happy to require the user has JS.

Secondly - **how do I do it?**

The simplest idea: `$(document).live("submit", myTokenAddFn);` doesn't work.

The token injection part is proving very tricky since, as I said, the web app is very large, and there a number of bridges to cross:

- There are forms that are created (using JS) after the page has loaded
- We make use of JSF (which has onclick attributes on anchor tags to submit forms)
- There are instances of jQuery form submits using AJAX
- There are plenty of onclick handlers attached to form submit elements already

I feel I am very close but I can't believe I'm not impacting performance on slower browsers. I am starting to think that there might be a better way.

**What I have done:**

- *To overcome jQuery AJAX form submissions:* Using the [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) method to append my token to the real data values before the AJAX request is sent
- *To add the token to simple form elements on the page that are there on page load:* On page load effectively loop through forms and add the token, then add jQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) that says this form has the token (to improve performance of next step)
- To overcome dynamically created forms: `$("input[type='submit'],input[type='image'],button,a[onclick]").live("mousedown", myTokenAddFn);`
  The above line copes with a lot and the 'myTokenAddFn' actually just loops through the page again looking for all forms that don't have the jQuery data item I added on page load.
  It copes with JSF forms that are submitted with an anchor tag's onclick attribute, buttons that don't reside in a form but submit a form and ensures that the token is always added before any other onclick handler submits the form (that might be present).

***The latest issue:***

A JS form is dynamically added to the page and the user submits it using the enter key while the cursor is in an input text field. The user (thanks to my Java Servlet) is logged out.

The easiest fix would be to include keypress listeners to all input elements, but the performance hit here worries me.

**Any suggestions? Ideas for a fresh start?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, use a captcha or similar technology, something that changes every so often or every request, this is all just silly, verify and check on the server whos posting what, and how often could be better than just overloading ur browser to do things that can be bypassed anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple idea, you're binding the event to `document`, but I'd bind the live listener to `"form"` - selecting all form tags. Also, in the event listener, just add `e.preventDefault()`. Like so:

```
$("form").live("submit", submitListener);

function submitListener(e) {
   // your handling stuff goes here
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

I've done the above method on my forms before and it seems to work fine. Hope this does the trick!

**EDIT:** I just wanted to be sure this actually works, [so here's a quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/skSw8/). As you can see, it blocks the submission to google.com and flashes up with a "nope!" to show the submission was blocked.

Comment: This does seem to be work...slightly frustrating that I put in so much work - swear I tried this (both $(document) and $("form")). Well, thanks anyway.

Comment: Just thinking, this of course misses JS myForm.submit() calls :( see http://jsfiddle.net/edslocombe/skSw8/16/

Comment: Hey Ed, check the latest version here, for how I would handle it: http://jsfiddle.net/skSw8/17/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing too much with the HTML structure, I've created another approach. Set a cookie before the page unloads, and perform a check on the existence and validity of the cookie at the server's side.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    //30 seconds SHOULD be enough to connect to the server
    document.cookie = "crf=" + myTokenAddFn() + "; max-age=30";
});
```

Comment: Maybe this is my answer...I was looking to avoid non-JS changes because the servlet is working well and has already been through testing but perhaps this change is needed.

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of jQuery:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

With newer versions of jQuery, but allowing form submissions on forms that have data-bypass:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form:not([data-bypass])", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Reference:

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

Look how Addy Osmani handles hijacking anchor tags.